# New to Python.. Gradepoint AVG?

Tags: python

Rather than asking the user to enter a number, modify gpa.py to enter 5 grades, but make it letter grades
(A, A-, B+, etc). Please input these grades, convert them to 4 point scale equivalents, (a=4.0, a- = 3.7, B+ =3.3, B= 3.0, B- = 
2.7, C+ =2.3, C = 2.0, C- =1.7 etc.). Print out the numeric equivalent of the average of these 5 grades.

originally for the first program i did i had

```
print("This program calculates grade point average.")
g1 = float(input("Enter course 1 grade -> "))
g2 = float(input("Enter course 2 grade -> "))
g3 = float(input("Enter course 3 grade -> "))
g4 = float(input("Enter course 4 grade -> "))
g5 = float(input("Enter course 5 grade -> "))
sum = g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5
count = 5
print ("Your GPA for last semester was -> ", sum / count)
```

but after reading this it tells me it wants me to assign grades, so i made it this

```
print("This program calculates grade point average.")
g1 = a
g2 = b
g3 = c
g4 = c+
g5 = b-
sum = g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5
count = 5
print ("Your GPA for last semester was -> ", sum / count)
```

how can i make the grades from strings to ints and then give the grade point average?

Comment: Try using a dictionary.

Comment: `sum` and `count` are both existing Python function. Try not to name your variables Python functions or keywords or you will shadow them.

Comment: Eh? `count` isn't a built-in function.

Comment: @Matt They needn't hide the fact that it is homework [as long as they ask their question properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Kevin Well, it is a method off of `str` and `list`, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` as suggested to map note letters to their numerical equivalent. Do not forget to surround it with a `try` in case of a wrong grade is given (i.e. Z).
Also, it is way more readable to use lists and loops instead of repeating the same code.

```
# Grades dictionnary
letter_grades = {
    'A' : 4.0,
    'A-' : 3.7, 
    'B+' : 3.3, 
    'B' : 3.0, 
    'B-' : 2.7, 
    'C+' : 2.3, 
    'C' : 2.0, 
    'C-' : 1.7,
    # and so on...
}

# Total grades
grades_number = 3
# List of grades
grades = []

print("This program calculates grade point average.")
for i in range(grades_number):
    grade = input("Enter course {} grade -> ".format(i+1))
    grades.append(grade)

try:
    # We try to sum the grades, but if a given one is wrong, then a KeyError with be thrown
    sum = sum([letter_grades[i] for i in grades])
    print ("Your GPA for last semester was -> ", sum / len(grades))
except KeyError:
    print("You entered a wrong grade.")
```

Comment: Awesome, i was able to make everything work the way i have wanted it to, the dictionary helped a ton, but once inputted that i was coming to a syntax error that said
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/letterstonbrs.py", line 29, in <module>
    print ("Your GPA for last semester was -> ", total / totalgrades)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'"
And i saw that you had the letter_notes[g1], which explained exactly what i was having trouble with, (i orignally had it as grades so i put grades instead of letter_notes)
Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved which helps others to notice but also gives me points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` to lookup numeric values based on the input string

```
>>> grades = {'A':4.0, 'A-':3.7, 'B+':3.3, 'B':3.0 ... etc}
>>> grades['B']
3.0
```

Comment: This helped a lot, it explains exactly what I was looking for, to be able to make a string into an int, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a long of way of accomplishing the task. Use dictionaries like the user above has demonstrated. They can grow and decrease in size and will be much easier storing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten it to work!

```
grades = {
'A':4.0,
'A-':3.7,
'B+':3.3,
'B':3.0,
'B-':2.7,
'C+':2.3,
'C':2.0,
'C-':1.7,
'D+':1.3,
'D':1.0,
'D-':0.7,
'F':0.0
}

print("This program calculates grade point average.")


g1 = grades['C']
g2 = grades['A']
g3 = grades['F']
g4 = grades['B-']
g5 = grades['D+']
total = g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5
totalgrades = 5
print ("Your GPA for last semester was -> ", total / totalgrades)
```

Adding a dictionary helped the most. But I came to a point where i was getting an error at the 20th line(g1 = grades['A']) 
I had not put the grades part before ['A'] and thats what was wrong with it. all works now and good to go. Thank you everyone for the help.